# Prompt before close

Tags: ms-access, vba

Before the user closes the form I want to prompt with a confirmation box.

I am not sure how to do this.
I have tried the code below and it prompts the user but upon clicking no it closes the form anyway:

```
Private Sub Form_Close()
    If MsgBox("Test", vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "Confirm close") = vbYes Then
    Else
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [access vba How to cancel a form close in Close Event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818836/access-vba-how-to-cancel-a-form-close-in-close-event)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't cancel the close event but you can cancel the unload event

```
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)

    If MsgBox("Test", vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "Confirm close") <> vbYes Then
         Cancel = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You can even get rid of the `if`. Just `Cancel = (MsgBox(...)=vbYes)`

Comment: is it possible to prompt only once before closing?

Comment: Right now it prompts every time the user clicks on close.

Comment: ?? - if they cancel the close and then close again then yes the prompt is going to come up again - what kind of behaviour do you want??